# How to display jMeter assertion results in the performance report in Jenkins? What constitutes an error in the performance report?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I have installed the jMeter plug-in for Jenkins and I can see the performance report based upon the jtl file that my jmx file generates.  In my jmx file, I have several Response Assertion listeners.  Based upon the jtl file that it generates, the assertion responses are false.  However, when I look at the performance report in Jenkins, it is showing 0 in the percentage of errors.  My first question would be, what constitutes an error in the performance report?  And secondly, how can I see which of the response assertion listeners returns false in the performance report in Jenkins?

Comment: What versions are you using? [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and [Performance Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What constitute an error in the performance report is determined by the percentage of errors that the samples find

To see what the error is go to
last build->Peformance Report

you should see a listing of all of the samples in your jmeter test plan and the results

Then select the sample name and you should see a the results for the sample taken